# Flux. Is there a way to retry on the last element?

Tags: java, flux, reactive

Does Flux allow to retry an operation on an occurred exception without taking the pointer to the initial position? I mean from the "problematic" element.

For example:

```
Flux.fromArray(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3})
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .doOnNext(i -> {
            System.out.println("i: " + i);
            if (i == 2) {
                System.out.println("2 found");
                throw new RuntimeException("2!!!!!!!1");
            }
        })
        .retry(2)
        .subscribe();
```

will have the following output:

```
i: 1
i: 2
2 found
i: 1
i: 2
2 found
i: 1
i: 2
2 found
```

when I would wish to see such an output:

```
i: 1
i: 2
2 found
i: 2
2 found
i: 2
2 found
```

P.S. `skipUntil` is not what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of, but I could be wrong.

However, you could provide that logic yourself for that particular step. For instance, but creating your own Consumer and wrapping the retry logic in it

```
public class RetryConsumer<T> implements Consumer<T> {

    private int                 retryCount;
    private Consumer<? super T> delegate;

    public RetryConsumer(int retryCount, Consumer<? super T> delegate) {
        this.retryCount = retryCount;
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(T value) {

        int currentAttempts = 0;
        while (currentAttempts < retryCount) {
            try {
                delegate.accept(value);
                break;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                currentAttempts++;
                if (currentAttempts == retryCount) {
                    throw e;
                }
                //Still have some attempts left
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You could then reuse this in your Flux steps, i.e.

```
Flux.fromArray(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3})
    .doOnNext(new RetryConsumer<>(2 , i -> {
        System.out.println("i: " + i);
        if (i == 2) {
            System.out.println("2 found");
            throw new RuntimeException("Error");
        }
     }))
     .subscribe();
```

Comment: Interesting, but generally follows the approach of `skipUntil`, which has issues when I replace the Integers with immutable stateless objects, which I try to process only once and with a `retry` for a few possible fails.